# How to encode with JS

Tags: javascript, utf-8, encode

I'm trying to generate some signature for third-party API and I get following error: Partner is not authorized. which means that I didn't encode my search term or create the signature.

Signature is encoded hashed value of timestamp, access key, and query terms.

Bellow is my code:

```
const timestamp = Date.now();
const searchTerm = encodeURI(this.state.searchText);
const signature = sha1(timestamp + searchTerm);
```

Third 
For web page safety, the query term should be JavaScript encoded before it's rendered to the page. Here's an example: 
queryTermEncoded = '@HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(queryTerm)';

How to encode timestamp and signature from above, seems like encodeURI is not working and I can't encode?
I need somehow to encode timestamp and searchTerm.

Here are some examples that are written in Java, Ruby, etc.

http://www.infospace.com/partners/sdk/csr/signingSample.html

Comment: you tagged as javascript but put code with ASP.NET MVC, can you explain better what you need ?

Comment: Code is pure JS written in React. Examples are in other languages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the C# example I think that the problem was with the date and the encodeURI, try this:

```
// now UTC
var date = new Date(Date.now());
// add 30 seconds like the examples
date.setSeconds(date.getSeconds() + 30);
// format to "yyyyMMddHHmm"
const timestamp = date.toISOString().replace(/[^0-9]/g, '').substr(0, 12);

// dont need to encode
const searchTerm = this.state.searchText; 

// hash timestamp + token + searchTerm
const signature = sha1(timestamp + token + searchTerm);
```

Comment: the time must be UTC, I made a small change on the first line, please try again with: var date = new Date(Date.now());

Comment: This is actual explanation:
Start with the UTC/GMT time
Round to the nearest minute (30 seconds or greater rounds up, otherwise round down)
Format the time as a string: yyyyMMddHHmm
yyyy - 4 digit year
MM - 2 digit month, 01-12
dd - 2 digit day, 01-31
HH - 2 digit hour, 24-hour clock, 00-23
mm - 2 digit minute, 00-59
Concatenate the values together in the following order:
timestamp
access key
query term(s)
Decode concatenated string into its binary representation according to whatever encoding it follows (likely UTF-8).

Comment: Perform a SHA-1 hash of the binary value.
Encode the hashed value using the url-safe base-64 encoding method, see http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4648#section-5

Comment: This is the thing - Format the time as a string: yyyyMMddHHmm

Comment: wow, stop, look at the header of the examples page: 

Restrictions - DO NOT USE JAVASCRIPT TO GENERATE THE SIGNATURE!
Using JavaScript will result in invalid signatures

Comment: Already saw that but contacted them and they say it's ok to use JS to generate signature